# Apache redirect of a node app to a folder with .htaccess

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a shared hosting. The domain `mydomain.com` points to `/home/myuser/www`, and I have my app in `/home/myuser/www/myapp`. I want to access to my node app via `mydomain.com`, and I think have to redirect  via `.htaccess` file. All my assets are built to `/dist` folder in the app, with `server.js` in `/dist/server.js`.

I have this configuration, but it fails:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/myapp$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/myapp/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:4000/$1 [P,L]
```

In local my app is happily running in `http://localhost:4000`; how should I configure the `/home/myuser/www/.htaccess` file?

Comment: It fails how?  Put `LogLevel debug` to see more details, and post here.  Also does your application respond at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Where should I add LogLevel debug? How do I check the access to `http://127.0.0.1:4000`?

Comment: Hi Nikita. I have provided the solution for your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem up vote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same

Comment: The `LogLevel` should be added in the VirtualHost that services your web site, or globally in the configuration file.  Note that this will produce a *LOT* of logs, you can turn it off when done.  To check access to the application, you can use the browser directly to that http link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **mod_proxy** for the same. (It is **enabled by default** in apache, but make sure it is).

The rule will be

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

The above rule is passing all the root request to internal port of your Node JS app with out user knowing about it (different from a rewrite)

> Do restart the apache server for the effects to be seen.

You can also refer the [blog post](https://linuxtogether.org/configuring-reverse-proxy-for-node-using-apache-mod-proxy/) for the same